# Original examples of functions of slow increase in the spirit of Jakimczuk

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, examples, limits-and-convergence

I believe that it is possible to prove that $$f(x)=e^{\operatorname{Ai}(x)}\log x$$ is a function of *slow increase* in the spirit of the definition given by the author of [1], where $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ denotes the Airy function. Now I don't know if my example follows easily from  the theorems of the article [1], or it is from the definition.

With independence of the applications to integer sequences, I think that these functions are interesting also in real analysis and were studied in the first section of the  article, with consequences as **Theorem 6** or other limits.

> **Question.** Is it possible to show other different and original example of function of slow increase in the spirit of the definition due to Jakimczuk, and as a consequence of it an unexpected claim illustrating such example? **Many thanks.**

Thus I am asking about , if possible, other special functions or techniques to create unexpected functions that fits the cited definition, and if it is  possible to provide some original consequence for this new example.

### References:

[1] Rafael Jakimczuk, *Functions of Slow Increase and Integer Sequences*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 13, Article 10.1.1 (2010).

Answer (score 2):

if $f(x)=e^{\operatorname{Ai}(x)}\log x$, then (because $\operatorname{Ai}(x)\rightarrow (4\pi)^{-1/2}x^{-1/4}e^{-\frac{2}{3}  x^{3/2}}$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$)
$$g(x)=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}\rightarrow\frac{1}{\log (x)}$$
for $x\rightarrow\infty$, so indeed $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ and therefore $f(x)$ is "slowly increasing" as defined by [R. Jakimczuk](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JIS/VOL13/Jakimczuk/jakimczuk8.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.